# Cannot call value of non-function type: UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've a *Swift* class that extends from `UITableViewController`. It has this function

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {...}
```

There's need that, I need to call this function programatically at one place and when I write

```
self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: 1)
```

- I get, **Cannot call value of non-function type 'UITableView!'**

How can I call this function programatically?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to (you're not supposed to) call that delegate/datasource method directly. UITableView has a func for that:

```
tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

Just create the index path based on your row, like:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`cellForRowAt` takes an `IndexPath`, not an `Int`:

```
func someFunc(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
    print(cell)
}
```